# PHP - UPLOADED FILE NAME IS EMPTY enctype set

Tags: php, html

This is my html:

```
  <form name = "picture" action = "upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="poza" id = "profilh" onmouseover="profilehov()" onmouseout="profileleave()" onchange="javascript:document.forms['picture'].submit();"></form>
```

And this is my php:

```
   $profile = $_POST['poza'];
   if($profile){
   $add = $profile['poza']['name'];
   $userem = $info['email'];
   $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
   $check = explode(".",$add);
   $extension = end($check);
   if((($_FILES['poza']['type']=="image/gif")||($_FILES['poza']['type']=="image/jpeg")||($_FILES['poza']['type']=="image/jpg")||($_FILES['poza']['type']=="image/png") &&($_FILES['poza']['size']<51000))&& in_array($extension,$allowedExts)){
    if(file_exists("uploads/".ENCRYPTION($userem)."/".$add)){
        $errors+=1;
    }
   if($errors == 0){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['poza']['tmp_name'],"uploads/".ENCRYPTION($userem)."/".$add);
$sql1 = "UPDATE **** SET ****= **** WHERE **** = ****";
$res1 = mysqli_query(****,$sql1) or die (mysqli_error(****));
}
    }
     }
```

The problem that i have is that the $add variable is empty....why?

P.S: Everything else seems to work fine.

Comment: You should check `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php   everything to do with uploaded files is in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$add = $profile['poza']['name'];
```

is wrong. Use the `$_FILES` global:

```
$add = $_FILES['poza']['name'];
```

The name of the file in the form field `poza` is retrieved.

Likewise,

```
$_FILES['poza']['tmp_name']
```

is the local filename.

Comment: i forgot to mention..i used $_FILES there but i had the same result..so i changed it to $profile :(

Comment: @SpiderLinked make sure `$profile` is `$_FILES['poza']`, not `$_POST['poza']`.

Comment: I will (once those 10 minutes have passed)